# Kotlin Android seqentially show couple of already defined layout activities

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have inherited piece of a code, and want to view  all the layout activities alreaady designed in the app as xml files which are many. Yes, I know I can review them in AS, but I want to view them on the real screen of the view smartphones I own. I can see 2 of such designed layout activities, but it does not allow to see 3, 4 or more..., not sure why.. Tried couple of possibilities here, so far no solution.

```
package com.explore.appviews

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.util.*
import kotlin.concurrent.schedule

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_launch)


        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
         // setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image_viewer)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        }, 3000)

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image_viewer)
         //   setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        }, 3000)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but you're queueing up two layout changes 3 seconds in the future, i.e. at the exact same time. So the first will display, and get immediately replaced by the second one. You're probably seeing `first_launch`, and then three seconds later `fullscreen_image_viewer`?

You should probably just make a list of all your layout resources, then post a delayed task that shows the next one in the list, and posts a new delayed task if there's more

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val layouts = listOf(
        R.layout.activity_first_launch,
        R.layout.activity_login,
        R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image_viewer
    )

    var nextLayout = 0
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    fun showNext() {
        // if we've hit the end, this skips and ends the posting cycle
        if (nextLayout < layouts.size) {
            setContentView(layouts[nextLayout])
            nextLayout++
            // run this function again in 3 seconds
            handler.postDelayed(::showNext, 3000)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        showNext()
    }
}
```

or a `Stack` would be neater, no need to keep track of the current position and check the bounds of the list

Comment: Thank you! That is indeed what I want to be able to review all the layouts defined.

Comment: And yes, if you turn device horizontally it restarts the slide show.. Not sure why, but nice... Thanks again it saves me a day or two!

Comment: Yeah when you rotate it destroys the activity so you'll lose that state - you could always override ``onSaveInstanceState`` and stick the current value in the bundle with a key. Then modify ``onCreate`` to pull the value out, and use 0 for the default value parameter, and set ``nextLayout`` to that before you call ``showNext()``.